# How to pass dynamically fetched image array data in react native grid image viewer with caption in react native

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

I am using the `react-native-grid-image-viewer-with-caption` plugin to display the image gallery on click it converts to slider.

**Below is the code for same:**

````
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {useContext, useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  Image,
  TouchableOpacity,
  ScrollView,
  ImageBackground,
  Platform,
  Linking,Share,
  ActivityIndicator, Button, TextInput, Touchable
} from 'react-native';
import GridImageViewerCaption from 'react-native-grid-image-viewer-with-caption';


const TestScreen = ({ route, navigation }) => {
  const [imageList, setImageList] = useState([]);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchimages();
    const gallery = [
       { image: 'https://via.placeholder.com/300/09f.png', text: 'Caption 1'},
        { image: 'https://via.placeholder.com/300/09f.png', text: 'Caption 2'},
        { image: 'https://via.placeholder.com/300/09f.png', text: 'Caption 3'},
        { image: 'https://via.placeholder.com/300/09f.png', text: 'Caption 4'},
        { image: 'https://via.placeholder.com/300/09f.png', text: 'Caption 5'},
        { image: 'https://via.placeholder.com/300/09f.png', text: 'Caption 6'},
        { image: 'https://via.placeholder.com/300/09f.png', text: 'Caption 7'},
        { image: 'https://via.placeholder.com/300/09f.png', text: 'Caption 8'}
        
    ];
    
  }
  const fetchimages = async () => {
    setImageLoading(true)
    var InsertAPIFETCH = 'https://testapi.com/images';
    var headers = {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    };
    var Data = {
      id: route.params.id,
    };
    fetch(InsertAPIFETCH, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: headers,
      body: JSON.stringify(Data),
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {
        setImageList(responseJson.imageres);
        
      })
      .catch(error => {
        alert(error);
      });
  }
 
  if (isLoading == true) {
    return <LottieView
    source={require('../assets/indicator.json')}
    autoPlay
    loop={true}
    speed={0.8}
    style={{ justifyContent: "center", flex: 1 }}
    />
  } else {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <GridImageViewerCaption data={gallery} captionColor="#fff" />      
      </View> 
    );
  }
}

export default TestScreen;```
````

I want to pass the API JSON response to the gallery function which intern will be passed to **GridImageViewerCaption**. More detailed elaboration is shown in the images attached.

Can anybody pls help me with this
RefLink: https://github.com/ansh-099/react-native-grid-image-viewer

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make gallery variable as default value of imageList and use imageList as data in GridImageViewerCaption

```
  const gallery = [
   { image: 'https://via.placeholder.com/300/09f.png', text: 'Caption 1'},
    { image: 'https://via.placeholder.com/300/09f.png', text: 'Caption 2'},
    { image: 'https://via.placeholder.com/300/09f.png', text: 'Caption 3'},
    { image: 'https://via.placeholder.com/300/09f.png', text: 'Caption 4'},
    { image: 'https://via.placeholder.com/300/09f.png', text: 'Caption 5'},
    { image: 'https://via.placeholder.com/300/09f.png', text: 'Caption 6'},
    { image: 'https://via.placeholder.com/300/09f.png', text: 'Caption 7'},
    { image: 'https://via.placeholder.com/300/09f.png', text: 'Caption 8'}
];

  const [imageList, setImageList] = useState(gallery);

  <GridImageViewerCaption data={imageList} captionColor="#fff" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but how to handle text(caption) in this

Comment: you can use array map to handle the caption.

`const responseJson = ['url1', 'url2', 'url3']; `
 `const newImageList = responseJson.map(url => ({ image: url, text: 'caption', }));`
`setImageList(newImageList);`
I hope it can help you.